# Cakephp Polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, database-relations

I am developing an user system, this system has 3 types of users:

1. Company employers
2. Clients
3. Providers

All users has many properties so i distribuite in users tables with login information and profiles tables with users details

My schema is something like this:

**users** (with username, email, password, profile_id)

**user_profiles** (for company employers information)

**client_profiles** (for client information)

**provider_profiles** (for providers details)

Im working with **CakePHP 2.x** and need to declare the relationship between **profile_id** field of my **users** table and my three types of profiles users tables
Researching on internet i found this is something called *polymorphic* relationship, **Laravel** has something like this:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations
but obviously i cant change the framework

I hope somebody could show how to declare this relation in **CakePHP** if it is possible

If you need more information about the problem please ask me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks but my point is i need relate the profile_id field of my users table with different tables (user_profiles, client_profiles, provider_profiles) depending of the user type
Im not trying to apply polymorphisme of OOP if your mean that 
In simple PHP is easy but using CakePHP i dont know how declare this relation, not even if exist. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward solution would be: add all three `xyz_profile_id` fields to the `users` table and define in the model-validate rules, that all three fields can be empty. You have to check that the right table is connected to your user in the controller. But in my opinion this would be more simple than fiddling around in each and every controller action, which table is actually associated with this column.

if the three tables have nothing in common, they should not share the same id-reference column. When they all have the same columns, why not merging them to the users-table?